# A strange limit

Tags: analysis, limits

I have to compute the following limit
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x\log(1+\tan(8x))}{6^{x^2}-1}.$$

Is that a problem if $\log(1+\tan(8x))$ is not always defined? Why not?

Comment: It is a problem if $\tan(8x)$ is undefined for arbitrarily large $x$.  And that is your situation.  So I would say your problem has no answer.

Comment: Indeed the limit at infinity wouldn't be defined.

Comment: Can you give me more details? Why $\tan(x)$ is undefined for arbitrary large $x$? It is the same for $\sin(x)$?

Comment: @Wishingwell: why?

Comment: Limit at infinity of a function says for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists some $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x>\delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ where $L$ is the proposed limit. However, no matter what $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ we pick, there will be some $x >\delta$ where $\tan(8x)$ is not defined.

Comment: @user119319 : regarding the "second question": the limit doesn't exist for the reasons given above.  I'm not totally sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Wishingwell If you replace "for all $x>\delta$" with "for all $x$ in the domain of the function such that $x>\delta$" then the limit makes sense; this is often the definition.

Comment: $\tan(x)$ is defined for all $x$, as long as $\cos(x)\not=0$, isn't it? For any $y$, I can find $x>y$ with $cos(x)\not =0$. In this sense $tan$ is defined for "arbitrarily" large numbers.  @StephenMontgomery-Smith

Comment: What I meant was: given any number $N$, there exists $x \ge N$ such that $\tan(8x)$ is undefined.  That is, there exist arbitrarily large counterexamples.

Comment: And what if we consider "egreg's" definition of limit?

Comment: What @egreg suggests is not "often the definition".  Even if that suggestion were adopted, the limit would still fail to exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if we proposed to use a modified definition of the tangent function  $$T(x) = \begin{cases} \tan x, & x \in \left[\pi k, \frac{\pi}{2}(2k+1)\right), \\ 0, & {\rm otherwise,} \end{cases} \quad k \in \mathbb Z$$ the limit STILL would not exist.  To understand why, we again look at the definition of limits at infinity:  The limit of a function $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ equals $L$ if, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $x_0$ such that **for all** $x > x_0$, $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.  If we posit that $L = 0$ for $$ f(x) = \frac{x \log (1 + T(8x))}{6^{x^2} - 1}, $$ then we can see the definition still is not satisfied no matter how large we wish to pick $x_0$ and how small we pick $\epsilon$.  For there must exist an integer $K$ such that $\frac{\pi}{2}(2K-1) \le x_0 < \frac{\pi}{2}(2K+1)$, and in the interval $(x_0, \frac{\pi}{2}(2K+1))$, there is guaranteed to be a value of $x$ such that $|f(x)| > \epsilon$ because the denominator is at most $6^{((2K+1)\pi/2)^2} - 1$ but the numerator can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $x$ just shy of the upper bound.*  So here we have an example of a function that is defined everywhere and is equal to the original function using the tangent over their common domain, but for which the limit is still not defined.

*Explicitly, on the interval $(x_0, \frac{\pi}{2}(2K+1))$ we can write $$ f(x) = \frac{x \log(1 + T(8x))}{6^{x^2}-1} > \frac{x_0 \log(1 + T(8x))}{6^{((2K+1)\pi/2)^2} - 1} > \epsilon,$$ and solving for $x$ gives $$\tan 8x > \exp\left(\frac{\epsilon}{x_0}(6^{((2K+1)\pi/2)^2} - 1)\right) - 1.$$  Since the RHS is some fixed constant, say $C$, there is always an $x$ in the interval such that $\tan 8x > C$.

Comment: Just a question: why you don't consider the fact that $1+\tan(8x)$ is not always positive? Is that irrelevant?

Comment: I see what you mean.  The above can be easily modified to account for that; e.g., you can take the absolute value of the tangent, or you can set the undefined parts to zero.  The same result holds.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Unfortunately I can't vote up (I have only 8 of reputation).